# Official source for QGIS icons or banners?

Tags: qgis

I am going to use maps and analysis results generated by QGIS in a presentation. Besides citing the [official reference](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Citation_Repository) i want to show a small QGIS icon or Banner on the first slide. 
I found some nice examples on the net ([1](http://www.vorarlberg.at/jpg/qgis_icon1.jpg))([2](http://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/chrome/site/qgis-icon.png)), but i wonder if there is an official source providing a QGIS (and maybe GRASS) icon for such purposes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find QGIS icons and images included with the installation: C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\qgis\images\icons

I imagine that this is about as official as you can get.

[This page](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/10/) shows you how to reference software and associated files if that is relevant to your presentation.

Comment: Ahh, of course. I didn't considered the actual install. On linux (debian) the icons can be found here: /usr/share/qgis/images/icons . Anyone has a vector image available?

Comment: There is an SVG folder included in the install as well, but it doesn't look like it includes any GIS-specific files - mostly symbology.

Comment: correct, the svg is for labeling. Maybe the developers or a nice volunteer icon designer could add the icons to the offical qgis wiki to make them more accessible for everyone. IMHO Opensource GIS software needs to be cited and displayed more!

Answer (score 4):

You could go one step up from a QGIS install and pull the icons from the QGIS GitHub repository. PNG (raster) and SVG (vector) icons are available:

https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/images/icons/qgis-icon.png
https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/images/icons/qgis_icon.svg

As for GRASS GIS, there are PNG and SVG icons available from their website:

http://grass.osgeo.org/download/logos/

http://grass.osgeo.org/uploads/images/logo/grasslogo_vector_big.png
http://grass.osgeo.org/uploads/images/logo/grasslogo_vector.svg

Answer (score 0):

Here are some used in the documentation: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/_images/

and http://robert.szczepanek.pl/icons.php