# Using internal QGIS icons / banner in own plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, icon

I have a problem using the internal symbols/icons in my plugin. For example I want to use the ["save" Symbol](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/images/themes/default/mActionFileSave.svg) in a `QToolButton` or the ["cancel" symbol](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/images/themes/default/mTaskCancel.svg) in a `QPushButton`.

I designed the GUI in `QT 5 Designer`. I also added the symbols to the button. After I compiled the `ui file` with `pyuic5` I changed the absolute path to the symbols to the relative path in my plugin folder after putting the downloaded `svg files` ([like its discribed here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58811/official-source-for-qgis-icons-or-banners) and [there](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152453/where-to-get-qgis-toolbar-icons)) in the plugin directory.

[image: Plugin folder overview]

Running the file `QgsAlkOsmCompare_dialog.py` in the terminal, produces this: 
All icons show up in their correct position (I cutted the screenshot because of its size).

[image: gui via terminal]

Opening my plugin in `QGIS` is functional, but the icons disappear. Even if I run the same `py file` in the  `./QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins folder` the plugin doesn't show the icons. I tried it with `png file` instead but nothing changed.

[image: gui in qgis]

Is it impossible to show buttons with icons in QGIS? I guess no, because I have seen icons in some of the GDAL processing functions too.

Can I import these internal QGIS icons in my GUI file or is it [compiled to the qgis.exe/qgis or some other kind of resource file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203663/missing-qgis-icon-resources-for-symbology-dialog)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation I finally found a solution!

**For some reason, the relative path to the icons was the Problem.**

So you need a implement a method, to get the **absolute path** to the folder which includes the icons. I found a simple and quick solution in the Plugin [`QuickOSM` by Etienne Trimaille](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickOSM/).

```
def resources_path(*args):
        """Get the path to our resources folder.

        :param args List of path elements e.g. ['img', 'logos', 'image.png']
        :type args: str

        :return: Absolute path to the resources folder.
        :rtype: str
        """
        path = dirname(dirname(__file__))
        path = abspath(join(path, pardir, 'resources'))
        for item in args:
            path = abspath(join(path, item))

        return path
```

You call the method while initializing the icon for the Object:

```
...
self.button_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(*yourQDialogName*)
icon = QtGui.QIcon(tools.resources_path("start.png"))
self.button_start.setIcon(icon)
...
```

Depending to your own folder structure you have to figure out what to use from `pardir`, `abspath` and `dirname`.

This solution worked for me on my Linux Mint 19.1 and Windows 8.1 Pro.

So, thanks o lot, Etienne Trimaille!

Comment: Nice I could help you. Credits go to the InaSAFE project where I copy/pasted this code. IMHO, it's always a pain for me to use `pyuic` to compile the file. Using this code, no need to compile the file everytime you change one icon.